# How to understand the colon symbol in directory path?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am unable to understand some of the syntax as below:

```
docker run -v $PWD/public/test/:/data/
```

Is there anyone familiar and comment simply so that I can understand and move on.

Comment: Have you read the doc?

Comment: Can you explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you about the documentation of `docker run`? Can you explain what research you have done, what you found during your research, and why that didn't answer your question? That way, you can prevent wasting answerer's time as well as wasting your own time, by preventing people from explaining things to you that you already know and you have already found to not help you.

Answer (score 2):

This tells `docker` to make the directory `public/test` available in the container as `/data`.

Example: The file `public/test/hello.html` (relative to your current working directory) can be accessed using `/data/hello.html` within the Docker container.

*Note: The command `docker run -v $PWD/public/test/:/data/` is incomplete. At least the image name (which could contain a `:` too, but with a different meaning) needs to be specified as well.*

---

In your example `$PWD/public/test/:/data/` is the *value* passed to the *option* `-v`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) this specifies a *volume*:

> `-v, --volume=[host-src:]container-dest[:<options>]: Bind mount a volume.`
>
> [...]
>
> The volumes commands are complex enough to have their own documentation in section *[Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)*. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> The `container-dest` must always be an absolute path such as `/src/docs`. The `host-src` can either be an absolute path or a `name` value. If you supply an absolute path for the `host-src`, Docker bind-mounts to the path you specify. If you supply a `name`, Docker creates a named volume by that `name`.

`$PWD` has nothing to do with the `docker` command. This instructs the shell you are typing this command in to replace it with the [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55190777) *before* it is passed to the `docker` command.

In your example `$PWD/public/test/` is an *absolute path* for the `host-src` and `/data/` is the `container-dest`.

Comment: This tells docker to make the directory public/test available in the container as /data.
Very much understandable. I really appreciate for your sharing

Comment: docker run -v $PWD/loimpute-public/test/:/data/ -it gencove/loimpute:latest -i /data/test_input.mp.gz -h /data/test_refpanel.vcf.gz -o /data/testout

Comment: Just need to run it as it is giving error of not finding vcf file in the directory